# Phonegap.js location

Tags: web-applications, cordova

I have a webapp that contains quite a lot javascript. Does it matter where I put the script tag for phonegap.js? Is it better to place it in the head instead of placing it at the very end of the page ?

Comment: I've always just placed it as the first script in the header and it's worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would place it as the first script of the page, but it should not really matter, exprect:

- you are loading REMOTE scripts, before you load you phonegap.js
- Do somethong BEFORE the deviceready event is fired.
- Have really large javascripts loaded before phonegap.js

As already said, you should load it as the first script.